# installed NordVPN app appears as icon, but won't open

Tags: software-installation, vpn, crash

Totally new to Ubuntu or Linux, came here after Win11 frustrated me one time too many. bear with me please.

I installed the NordVPN app as directed on their page, through the terminal. This seems to have worked - the app icon appears among the apps, and in the Ubuntu terminal, I can login and connect to the VPN both through command lines, and I have a VPN connection. That part seems to work.

However, I'd like the comfort of the app, not least because there I can SEE that I'm connected to VPN (in the terminal, I have no icons or anything, of course) - also change servers and all. When I click on the app icon, the graphics for "opening a window" come up (the window frame, increasing in size), but just for a split second, and just as an outline - then, nothing, no open window, no VPN app I can see. It seems like it tries to open it, but crashes in the process (?). Tried a few times, but no luck.

All the while, my connection stands (as evidenced by "show my IP" web pages; I have no other way of telling...)

I don't know if that's a general app problem, or one specific to this one?

Thank you!

Comment: You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; are you hoping we guess?  Please just tell us.  If it crashes, how did you determine that; was it *crash* files, in which case what did you see?  What was the crashing app? etc.. Please provide details.

Comment: Sorry! Of course. 23.04 desktop, installed on a lenovo desktop. Again, brand new here! Well, I said "it crashes" because when I clicked on the NordVPN app icon (I think I said that?), I saw it trying to open through the animation, but then nothing more happened there was no open window for the app. might well be it's running in the background and the windows doesn't come up; how would I know the difference?

Comment: Please provide additional details (*or any corrections*) to your question.  This is a Q&A (*Question & Answer*) site & not a forum (https://ubuntuforums.org/ is the Ubuntu Forums site).  Depending on app type, crash files are found in `/var/crash/` and can provide clues as to what is crashing, otherwise you can check what is running to see if it's in the background etc...  Any answers are made to your question, which still does not mention any OS/release details (doesn't mention 23.04 Desktop for example).

Answer (score 0):

Nordvpn app does not provide a GUI on linux. You might be interested in nordvpn extension in gnome or Nordvpn-Electron gui. Notice that these are third-party apps. I suggest you stick with the provided cli.

Comment: Thank you! that answers it. I expected a GUI. What happened was - the window it "opened" was actually the help terminal, which didn't open because my "actual" terminal was already open. Once that was closed, I got the help terminal when I clicked on NordVPN, showing commands. I think it all works as intended.